# Writing iff and if then statements using "not" and "and."

Tags: propositional-calculus

How can I write $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ using only $\neg$ and $\land$?

Comment: $P \to Q$ is $\lnot (P \land \lnot Q)$.

Comment: And $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is $(P \to Q) \land (Q \to P)$.

Comment: If $P\iff Q$ the we also have that $P\implies Q$. So writing $P\iff Q$ will suffice.

Comment: Thank you, the first question was answered using only $\land$ and $\neg$, but the second part you gave me the answer with an if\then and I am trying to figure out the answer with only  $\land$ and $\neg$?

Comment: @Eddie2020 What is your definition of $P \iff Q$? One possible definition is $(P \implies Q) \wedge (Q \implies P)$.

Comment: P if and only if Q.

Comment: @Eddie2020 How do you defined $P$ if and only if $Q$ then? Do you define it using truth table? (This is how it was done when I learned it.)

Comment: Yes, with a truth table. P if and only if Q is only true when they are both true or they are both false. I just dont know how to show this same thing using only $\land$ and $\neg$, like i said.

Comment: @Eddie2020 OK. Then I think you can check $P \iff Q$ is the same as $(P \implies Q) \wedge (Q \implies P)$ using truth table and then use it to obtain an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[$P \Rightarrow Q$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) is the same as $\lnot(P \land \lnot Q)$. This is a 'standard' substitution, but if you only remember that it's equivalent to $\lnot P \lor Q$ you can reach the desired form with [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Now, $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $(P \Rightarrow Q) \land (Q \Rightarrow P)$, so plugging in the first result we get $(\lnot(P \land \lnot Q)) \land \lnot(Q \land \lnot P)$.

Answer (score 0):

Another path to write $P\iff Q$ is to take the definition in your comment:

> $P$ if and only if $Q$ is only true when they are both true or they are both false.

So writing this formally,
$$(P\iff Q) = (P\land Q)\lor(\lnot P\land \lnot Q).$$
Now this is *almost* in the form you want, except for that $\lor$ in the middle. But for that you can use the relation
$$\lnot(A\lor B) = \lnot A\land\lnot B$$
from which you get through negation
$$A\lor B = \lnot(\lnot A\land\lnot B)$$
Now use $A=P\land Q$ and $B=\lnot P\land \lnot Q$ to arrive at
$$(P\iff Q) = \lnot(\lnot(P\land Q)\land\lnot(\lnot P\land\lnot Q))$$